# Running a function indefinitely at specific time of day in Python

Tags: python, loops, datetime, if-statement, while-loop

I have a function that I need to run everyday from 5pm to 9am the next day, then starts again at 5pm. Below is my implementation:

```
import datetime as dt
import time 
while True:
    if dt.datetime.now().hour < 9 or dt.datetime.now().hour > 17:
        #some irrelevant function here
        print('Function processing')
        time.sleep(1) 
    else:
        print("Not time yet")
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

The above code works, but I would like to also execute a function once every first loop at 5pm and after the last loop at 9am. My first instinct is to do something like this:

```
def starting(): print("It's 9pm, time to start!")
def ending(): print("It's 5am, time to end")
while True:
    if dt.datetime.now().hour < 9 or dt.datetime.now().hour > 17:
        if #this is the first loop since 5pm:
            starting()
        elif #this is the last loop at 9am:
            ending()
        #some irrelevant function here
        print('Function processing')
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Not time yet")
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

I am not sure if this is the most optimal way of doing it, would appreciate some ideas.

Comment: use CRON https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

Comment: sorry I am on Windows and I prefer a solution in an IDE such as Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: see https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10

Comment: Your function will run at 6pm, not 5pm.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, just mimic the same thing you've done:

```
#you can call your ending function here
if dt.datetime.now().hour == 17:
    do something

#you can call your starting function here
elif dt.datetime.now().hour == 9:
    do something different
```

This will perform actions based on the hour.